# Github actions, problem with dep installing

Tags: go, github-actions, dep

I have this go.yml for github actions

```
name: Test

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:

  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:

    - name: Set up Go 1.15
      uses: actions/setup-go@v2
      with:
        go-version: 1.15
      id: go

    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Get dependencies
      run: |
          if [ -f Gopkg.toml ]; then
              curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
              dep ensure
          fi

    - name: Build
      run: go build -v ./...

    - name: Test
      run: go test -v ./...
```

It builds with error: home/runner/work/project/project is not within a known GOPATH/src
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.

How to fix it problem?

Answer (score 1):

The default value of `GOPATH` is `$HOME/go`.

Your project folder is outside of this `GOPATH` hence the error.

You have two ways to fix this problem.

1. (Preferred) Update your project to use go.mod. It's the newer, nicer dependency management solution in go and doesn't require your project to be in `GOPATH`.

Assuming you are using Go version newer than 1.12, Remove the `Gopkg.toml` and `Gopkg.lock` (if you have it).

Run,

a. `go mod init <project-name>` Replace `<project-name>` with the name of your project.

b. Run `go mod tidy` and it'll add all the dependencies you are using in your project.

c. Run `go build` once to make sure your project still builds. If it doesn't, You can add the missing dependencies manually in `go.mod`.

Commit `go.mod` and `go.sum`(if you need deterministic builds).

Removed this from your CI config,

```
 if [ -f Gopkg.toml ]; then
              curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/golang/dep/master/install.sh | sh
              dep ensure
          fi
```

and just build the project. It should work.

2. Set the `GOPATH` correctly in your CI config before calling `dep ensure`.  I *think* `GOPATH=/home/runner/work/project/project` should work but I am not aware of the exact specifics related to `GOPATH` so you'll just have to try.